# Why my GPU load is low when is rendering a scene with Blender?

Tags: render, blender

I have a scene in Blender and I render it with GPU Compute, Cycles.

The problem is when the scene is rendering, my GPU load is under the 5% while the CPU is doing all the render work.

My GPU is a Nvidia GTX 745 and my Cpu an Intel core I5. The blender version that I am using for render is 2.82a.

Anybody knows why is this happening?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on blender.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go into the blender preferences, (edit>preferences>system>cycles render devices) and try looking for your GPU, as you may have 'none' selected.

[It might be under a different path tracing GPU option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T32c.png)